Combining fields in pivot table
I'm trying to use data which looks like this:



Client
Workstream
Project




Alpha
a; b; c
A


Beta
a; d; e
B


Gamma
b; c; e
C


Alpha
d
D


Beta
a; c; e
E



To produce a pivot table that functions like this (where I don't care about additional columns like 'Project' used as an example):



Client
a
b
c
d
e




Alpha
1
1
1
1
0


Beta
2
0
1
1
1


Gamma
0
1
1
0
2



Essentially, create a pivot table out of 'client' and 'workstream', but with 'workstream' separated by the semicolon delimiter. I could achieve this if I expanded out the table by making each workstream its own row, but I want to avoid this because it would make the table very large with a lot of redundant information, and also because I don't see a way to split text to rows (as opposed to columns).
I have tried splitting text into columns and creating a pivot table using these new fields in the 'columns' area of the pivot table, but this creates a huge mess. When I create a standard pivot table with the Client and Workstream as fields, this of course doesn't combine the different 'letters' of the workstream in a sum and created a column for each set of workstreams

For other methods to split data look at this question and the three examples. stackoverflow.com/q/72210897/5091720
Steps for Excel's Power Query

Click on Data>"From Table/Range"
Remove columns "Project"
Split Column by Delimiter and choose advance and choose rows
replace spaces with nothing
click the "Close & Load To..." choose pivot table
Make you pivot table with "Client" and "Workstream"
Pat yourself on the back.





Row Labels
a
b
c
d
e




Alpha
1
1
1
1



Beta
2

1
1
2


Gamma

1
1

1


Grand Total
3
2
3
2
3




Perfect, this does exactly what I wanted!
One minor change is I changed the delimeter to be custom, so that the delimeter is a semicolon with a space. That way I don't have to replace the spaces with nothing and for the real case, phrases are still readable.
Many thanks!
